# Disable some tabs when using ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to create a Wizard type of functionality in an Android app, with a couple of steps that need to be followed. Each of the steps is represented in its own fragment and all the fragments are placed in a FragmentPager. I am using ViewPagerIndicator [1] as well.

What I'm interested in is to somehow have some of the steps "disabled" (so not allowing the user to scroll to the corresponding fragments, although the tab headers are visible ). Basically the user would be able to navigate only to Step 1's tab at the beginning, then (after a validation) to tabs 1 and 2, then 1, 2 and 3 and so on...

Any ideas what would be the best way to implement something like this?

[1] - http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add the fragments when the user pass the validation?

After validation in FragmentTab1, add FragmentTab2 to the PageAdapter and notifyDataSetChange after every new addition.

If the PageAdapter class of that library doesnt do it, probably you'll need to rewrite some methods or create your own PageAdapter.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! This was actually my first thought, but how can I, in this case, still show the following tab headers, in a disabled style, so that the user is aware there are more steps to follow?

Comment: I have a possible trap for your problem. 
If you want to show the tab headers but disable the swipe. Rewrite your method getCount() in the PageAdapter, and return a var with the number of tabs you want to go. For example:

If you want to force the user to stay in Fragment1:

public static int COUNT = 1;

public int getCount(){

 return COUNT;

}

Then you can increase the var to enable more fragments. 

however, i thinks there is a better way to do it capturing the event and filter it if you want to pass to the next page or not. Sorry if I didnt help you, try to play with that adapter hh